# Handle Constructor in Calculating the Summation using java

Tags: java, constructor, java.util.scanner

I want to make a Calculation of insurance sum with Household insurance. The initial requirements are: 2 insurance products with different price per m²
1. Compact: 650 € per m²
2. Optimal: 700 € per m²
the 2 input of this program are:"Compact" or "Optimal"
and Living space in m².
And the output should be Insurance sum;
It is mandatory to note down that this program may be extended by other products with complicated calculations.

I am proceeding in this way, but as I am new in java, I am stuck in the situation how to handle the constructor. In my code I want to fix the compact and Optimal, but I want to get the value of Living space by user input, such as scanner class. How can I do this in this case.

```
My Insurance class 
public class Insurance {
  private Double Kompakt;
  private Double Optimal;

  public Insurance(Double kompakt, Double optimal) {

    this.Kompakt = kompakt;
    this.Optimal = optimal;
}

public Double getKompakt() {
    return Kompakt;
}

public void setKompakt(Double kompakt) {
    this.Kompakt = kompakt;
}

public Double getOptimal() {
    return Optimal;
}

public void setOptimal(Double optimal) {
    this.Optimal = optimal;
 }
}
```

My Sum Class is

```
public class Sum extends Insurance{

 private int livingSpace;

  public Summe(Double kompakt, Double optimal, int Wohnfläche) {
    super(1.0, 1.0);
    this.livingSpace=livingSpace;
    this.setCompakt(650.00); // I want to fix value of Compact
    this.setOptimal(700.00); // I want to fix Value of Optimal
    }


public double CompaktSum(){

        double sum= getCompakt()*livingSpace;
        return sum;
    }
    public double OptimalSum(){
        double sum =getOptimal()*livingSpace;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Now in my main class I want to set value of livingSpace manually but I can not call the constructor without the setting method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc1 =new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc2 =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1\tCompact: 650 € per m²\n2\tOptimal: 700 € per 
    m²");
    System.out.println("Please choose your 1 for Compact and 2 for product");
    int swichValue=sc1.nextInt();
    Summe hs=new Summe(1.0,1.0,5); // I am having problem here, I just want 
    //to call empty contructor so that I can set livingSpace manually

    switch(swichValue){
    case 1:{
    double res=hs.KompaktSumme();
    System.out.println("Versicherungssumme ist : "+res);
    break;
    }
    case 2:{
        double res=hs.OptimalSumme();
        System.out.println("Versicherungssumme ist : "+res);
        break;
    }
    case 3:{
        System.out.println("Error");

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: create another constructor -> that's called overload in java -> you can use two constructors in java with different parameters/arguments

Comment: @John Could you please explain how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly I'm not sure what exactly you wanna achieve, but if my understanding is correct.
To fix the values of Kompakt and Optimal, you can simply do this:

```
public class Insurance {
  private Double Kompakt = 700.0; // fixed value
  private Double Optimal = 600.0; // fixed value

  public Insurance() {} // empty constructor for the superclass

 /* you can change the values and get them by using the same getters and setters you already created*/
```

Now in the subclass

```
public class Summe extends Insurance{

 private int livingSpace;

  public Summe(int Wohnfläche) { // you can use this in future if you wnat
   // no need to call the superclass constructor 
      livingSpace = Wohnfläche;
    }

    // another constructor that overloads the first (i.e empty one)
      public Summe() {
       // no need to call the superclass constrictor 
      }

 // create a setter and a getter for the the livingSpace
 public void setLivingSpace (int livingSpace){
     this.livingSpace = livingSpace;
 }
```

now here you are

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc1 =new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc2 =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1\tCompact: 650 € per m²\n2\tOptimal: 700 € per 
    m²");
    System.out.println("Please choose your 1 for Compact and 2 for product");
    int swichValue=sc1.nextInt();
    Summe hs=new Summe(); 
    // set the values here manually as you described
    hs.setLivingSpace (0.5); // or whatever value, you may need to take it from user..etc 

    switch(swichValue){
    case 1:
          double res=hs.KompaktSumme();
          System.out.println("Versicherungssumme ist : "+res);
       break;

    case 2:
          double res=hs.OptimalSumme();
          System.out.println("Versicherungssumme ist : "+res);
        break;

    case 3:
         System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will try your code, and let you know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can overload your constructor. but Actually your code is not going to compile because the name of your class is `Sum` and the name of your constructor is `Summe`. The constructor should have the same name with the class.

```
public Sum() {
    super(650.00, 700.00);
}
```